# MSSQL db_datareader to All databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, users, read-only

I have 100 databases in MSSQL 2008 Server. I need to create a read only user to read all these databases. Is there a server wide role: db_datareader I can assigned the user to, so that I don't need to go through each database to add user mapping.

Thanks,
tim

For whom it may helps, this is my final script:

```
 --You will need Server Level's Login user123 created first.
 -- >=7 filtered out the system database, use this to find out your number
 -- EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'use ? SELECT DB_ID(), DB_NAME()'
 EXEC sp_MSForEachDB
   'USE ?
    IF DB_ID() >= 7 
    BEGIN
       CREATE USER user123 FOR LOGIN user123
       EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, user123
    END
   '
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB
  'USE ?
   IF DBID() >= 5 EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''MyUser'' '
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked well. 
The DBID() should be DB_ID() for me. Also I changed 5 to 7 due I have ReportServer databases installed. Thanks. 
Can use this to find out a list of database name and ID:

`EXEC sp_MSForEachDB

'use ?
SELECT DB_ID(), DB_NAME()'`